# Exporting Azure Enterprise Application Unique Claims ID

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml

I have a working script that gets the Azure Enterprise applications, but more specifically looking to add to the script to get the claims used, groups/users assigned, owner. I don't know if MS has exposed the information to gather the required claims (essentially the Unique Claim ID)?

Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object { ($*.AccountEnabled -contains "true") } | Select DisplayName, ObjectId, ServicePrincipalType, PublisherName,NameID, @{N="Tags";E={$*.Tags}}| Export-Csv C:\Temp\AzureApps.csv

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated!

I also tried doing the following to see if I could get the app name and SAML settings but failed.

Retrieve all enterprise applications
$enterpriseApplications = Get-AzureADApplication -All:$true

## Initialize an empty array to store the application data

$applicationData = @()

## Loop through each enterprise application and retrieve the attribute claims

foreach ($application in $enterpriseApplications) {
$attributeClaims = $application.Saml2Settings.AttributeConsumingServices.ServiceName.Attributes

```
# Initialize an empty object to store the application and attribute claim data
$applicationInfo = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    DisplayName = $application.DisplayName
    ApplicationId = $application.AppId
    AttributeClaims = ($attributeClaims | Select-Object DisplayName, Name)
}

# Add the application and attribute claim data to the application data array
$applicationData += $applicationInfo
```

}

## Export the application data to a CSV file

$applicationData | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\apps.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to move to [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-1.0). It's meant to replace AzureAD PowerShell.

##### To authenticate

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Policy.Read.All","Application.ReadWrite.All"
```

##### To get app roles (user/group/application) assigments:

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment  -ServicePrincipalId <oid>
```

##### To get owners:

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalOwner -ServicePrincipalId <oid>
```

##### To get SAML settings:

```
Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId <oid>|Select samlSingleSignOnSettings, loginUrl, logoutUrl, notificationEmailAddresses
```

##### To get claims mapping policies:

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalClaimMappingPolicy -ServicePrincipalId <oid>
```

##### To get token lifetime policies:

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalTokenLifetimePolicy -ServicePrincipalId <oid>
```

##### To get token issuance policies:

```
Get-MgServicePrincipalTokenIssuancePolicy -ServicePrincipalId <oid>
```

##### To get optional claims (from the application):

```
Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId <oid>|select OptionalClaims
```

For more information:

- [Using Connect-MgGraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/authentication-commands?view=graph-powershell-1.0#using-connect-mggraph)
- [application resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- [servicePrincipal resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0)